# Download File from HTTPS to computer using SSIS

Tags: https, ssis

Please I am trying to download a File from an HTTPS website.
i have created an HTTP Manager to connect to the website with my password and Username.
Now what do i do next to be able to the file with a certain format and dump in a specific folder on my computer?

Comment: Have you tried just using a URL with https on it? Does it need to be SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you are looking for 
http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx

Comment: it did not work for me. I am trying to download from an https not http.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
wc.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user-id", "password", "domain")
wc.DownloadFile("https://www.portal.zzz.com/sites/Document area/fff.xlsx", "C:\fff.xlsx")
```